# How to attach image by Javamail API(SMTP) on android

Tags: java, android, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm newbie android developer.
I'm can sent e-mail by SMTP successfully. But i can't attach image within e-mail. Please let me know. How to attach image with my e-mail.

sorry for my English language.

Config.java

```html
public class Config {
    public static final String EMAIL ="";
    public static final String PASSWORD ="";
}
```

MainActivity.java

```html
package com.example.rattapongt.androidsmtp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Declaring EditText
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextSubject;
    private EditText editTextMessage;

    //Send button
    private Button buttonSend;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing the views
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
        editTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

        //Adding click listener
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    private void sendEmail() {
        //Getting content for email
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString().trim();
        String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString().trim();

        //Creating SendMail object
        SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

        //Executing sendmail to send email
        sm.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendEmail();
    }
}
```

SendMail.java

```html
package com.example.rattapongt.androidsmtp;

/**
 * Created by Rattapongt on 2/16/2017.
 */

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


//Class is extending AsyncTask because this class is going to perform a networking operation
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    //Declaring Variables
    private Context context;
    private Session session;

    //Information to send email
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;

    //Progressdialog to show while sending email
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //Class Constructor
    public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message) {
        //Initializing variables
        this.context = context;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Showing progress dialog while sending email
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Sending message", "Please wait...", false, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Dismissing the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //Showing a success message
        Toast.makeText(context, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Creating properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        //Configuring properties for gmail
        //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values

                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");


        //Creating a new session
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                    }
                });

        try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Setting sender address
            mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
            //Adding receiver
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            //Adding subject
            mm.setSubject(subject);
            //Adding message
            mm.setText(message);

            //Sending email
            Transport.send(mm);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendmpr).